# How can I get total time online in Facebook in the last 30 days either via graph API or fql?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

How can I get my total online presence time in the last 30 days in Facebook either via graph API or fql?

Comment: I dont think such api call exists

Answer (score 13):

> **How to get the user's total online time spent on Facebook using MY
>   APP?**

This can be achieved by tracking the user activity while interacting with your application.

> **How to get the user's total online time spent on Facebook?**

Facebook will **not** share such information with you. (i.e. no API end-point exists for such task)